# Showing fixed point is hyperbolic for a map.

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

The discrete time dynamical system given is $f\left ( x \right )=ax^{2}\left ( x-1 \right )$:

i) Show that $x^{*}=0$ is a stable hyperbolic fixed point.

This is puzzling.

To compute the stability, we look at $\left | f'\left ( x \right ) \right |<1$.

$\left | 2ax-3ax^{2} \right |=0 <1$ so $x^{*}=0$ is stable.

However, the hyperbolicity of a fixed point is determined by the eigenvalue.
The eigenvalue is $2ax-3ax^{2}$. At $x^{*}=0$, the eigenvalue is 0 and so the it would be non-hyperbolic in contrast to what is required.

If someone could provide some illumination to my understanding, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you're talking about stability in two different scenarios: discrete dynamics (where we iterate a function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$) and continuous dynamics (where we study the flow $x'=f(x)$)). 

In the former case, a point $x_0$ is fixed if $f(x_0)=x_0$ and it's stable if $|f'(x_0)|<1$. In the latter case, the constant function $x(t)=x_0$ is a solution if $f(x_0)=0$ and it's stable if $f'(x_0)<0$. That second situation is often cast in terms of an eigenvalue when $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I assume the question is about map since "discrete" is often associated with maps. 
I understand what you're saying. If the above equation is a map, my solution is correct.